# vsnprintf and snprintf causing dll to not load

Tags: c#, c, .net, gcc, printf

I've been fighting this for days.  I have a Visual Studio .net project written in C# that needs to load a dll written in C using gcc compilers on the Codeblocks IDE.

The dll can be loaded and used fine, but when I use vsnprintf in the dll, the .net project says "Unable to load DLL.  The specified module could not be found." whenever I try to call a function from the dll.

Relevant C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Scratchpad
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        [DllImport("testpielibs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        static extern void SomeFunction(string a);    

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SomeFunction("ABC");
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant C (the DLL) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int  log_printf(char *format, ...)
{
    char msg[256];
    va_list ap;

    memset(msg, 0, sizeof msg);
    va_start(ap, format);
    vsnprintf(msg, 256, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that "SomeFunction" doesn't even call "log_printf".  The project builds fine regardless, and when I comment out the line with vsnprintf it works like it should with the .net project, but that one line is what's causing the dll to be unable to load in the .net project.

Incase this is releveant, here are my linker libraries for the dll:

```
ws2_32
iphlpapi
mswsock
winmm
user32
```

Also, I feel like it might be important to note that the other day, just before all of this happened, I got an error from codeblocks saying something about my config file being corrupted.  This project was building fine before then, but I had to go back and manually re-assign the compiler and linker settings.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: snprintf is causing the same issue.  I can use sprintf and vsprintf, but snprintf and vsnprintf are causing the dll to not be loaded in the C# project, even though the dll will still build with no errors or warnings.  I've looked into the calling conventions used to import my dll functions into my c# project, and Cdecl seems like the way to go since it specifically says that it "enables calling functions with varargs, which makes it appropriate to use for methods that accept a variable number of parameters, such as Printf."  I've also tried importing SomeFunction using calling conventions Winapi, StdCall and ThisCall, but they all have the same results.  Any help would be really appreciated, I have been stumped on this for a while.

Comment: Hi, I suspect that your "it might be important" statement is that, important. Can you get the version before the corruption? If not I think  you need to post the information related to building the DLL.

Comment: It was version 16.01.  It's still the same version.

Comment: This is an entirely normal mishap, making it specific to vsnprintf does make it much harder to explain.  Code compiled with GCC doesn't just have a dependency on the OS DLLs you listed, it also depends on the C runtime library.  If it can't be found at runtime then it is sayonara with this exception. memset() is a C runtime function as well, but is normally generated as an intrinsic so doesn't require the library.  Just use the normal troubleshooting strategies, enable loader snaps or use SysInternals' Process Monitor to diagnose DLL resolution problems.